# Using O Auth for google api on android app

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

What should i add here for the scheme for URl redirect, can i add anything, like "com.example.oauth/:oauth2redirect"(Package name:/ oauth2redirect)?.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oauth">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> 
</uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Oauth">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme=" ">
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: you can study this ,https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

Answer (score 0):

The most common option when learning Mobile OAuth is to start with a value like this, using a reverse DNS style of naming, to include your company + app names:

- com.mycompany.myapp:/callback

A good starting point for something to compare against is the [Android AppAuth Code Sample](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android), where you just specify a [scheme value in the gradle file](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/master/app/build.gradle).

If it helps, my [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/) has some step by step instructions to get the sample running.